# downloading multiple file with download manager using jsoup and asynctask, not happening

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

Here is my code:--

```
public class grabber extends Activity 
{


int counter;
String folderPath;
String[] array;
DownloadManager dm;
private long enqueue;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);

    Down t = new Down();
    t.execute();




}


private class Down extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.i("grabber", "in back");
String   w =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+"/Android/data/myfolder";
    createdir(w);


    String link = "http://mywebsitehere.com";


    Document doc;

      array = new String[200];
    try {

        doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        String title = doc.title();


         folderPath = w+ File.separator+title;

         createdir(folderPath);


        Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
         counter =0;

        for (Element image : images) 
        {
             String img = image.attr("src");
            array[counter]=img;

            counter++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
          "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Request request = new Request(
                    Uri.parse(array[i]));
            request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
              request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),folderPath,File.separator+"pic"+Integer.toString(i)+".jpg");
            enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);



        }


    }
 }




public void createdir(String Path)
{
File file = new File(Path);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.mkdirs();

    }

}
}
```

**What it should do:-**
    It should download the given links, which contains images, to the given path.

**What it does:-**
       The app is running quite fine, my UI is not hanging. After a few second **"done"** Toast is shown, which means the`asynctask` is completed and we are at `onPostExecute`. But when I check the dir I am seeing that there is no folder inside `Android/data/myfolder`.
The main setback is that some times it works, i.e. the images are downloaded and sometimes not.

So I am guessing maybe its because of some http timeout or some error which I am not handling correctly because I am using `createdir(folderPath);` after `Jsoup` and maybe the error is happening there so no folder is getting created there.

Any Ideas!?? Thanks in Advance.

Edit:-
I am getting `SocketTimeoutException` during jsoup.connect(link).get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with some trial and error.

We can use timeout option here to reduce the **Sockettimeoutexception** by changing

```
        doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

to

```
        doc = Jsoup.connect(link).timeout(10000).get();
```

And there is still one other error, thats to remove the Toast message in the **onPostExecute** as we cannot interact without handler from background task to UI.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following permission to the manifest of your application, to write to the external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope you did this?

Comment: Yup.. its like if I try 10 times,  thn one time I get luck and downloads happens.

Comment: Do you get a exception? You can also add a "try{}catch{}" to the "onPostExecute" method to log any errors.

Comment: The problem is during jsoup.connect(link).get() , when I am getting sockettimeoutexception